# Spring Boot doesn't resolve property placeholder in yaml for apring.profiles.active property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-profiles

I am used to feature that I can refer to another property from within .yml file using `${...}`.
So I have Spring Boot v2.3.0.RELEASE and following .yml:

```
env: dev
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${env}
```

But unfortunately, when running my application i see

```
The following profiles are active: ${env}
```

Despite the fact that this placeholder works perfectly in other properties, for example kafka topics i define as

```
topic: ${env}.topic_name
```

and i can see in logs that it's resolved properly

```
Kafka producer topic=dev.topi_name
```

Seems like `spring.profiles.active` is some sort of an exception from this rule, but i can't find why. And how can i get the same result (with profile depending on other property variable) as is, without env variables, external keys, setting in code, etc. ?

Comment: Set the logging level to TRACE and see & paste the outputs. maybe spring will hint something about why it refuses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in Spring Boot 2.4.0 as a part of the updated config file processing (more about it in [2.4.0 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#config-file-processing-application-properties-and-yaml-files)).

If interested, you can play with the new property `spring.config.use-legacy-processing` to see the difference in how `spring.profiles.active` is processed.